# Get Logical And result Of values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

i want to get logical and between values and get final result like this

```
declare @Result as int

set @result = 1 & 0 &  1 & 0
```

but values Getting from  some columns of table  from select result

in the other hand i want to conver   this C# code to sql server

```
bool x
int[] values[{1,0,1,0,1,0,5,4,0,10}]
for int (i = 0 ; i <10 i++)
{
x = values[0] & values[i];
}
```

Comment: SQL doesn't (in general) support arrays explicitly.  Can you show your table definition?

Comment: A lot of DB supports bitwise operation, do you have a specific one in mind?

Comment: my table defination is simple sample  one  integer column with  zero and one values for 5 records . i want to get the logical and result for records

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two strategies:

1. A User Defined Aggregate (requires SQL CLR). Define yourself an aggregate that can `AND` an arbitrary set of values. Unfortunately, SQL Server makes it quite hard to create custom aggregates. There's no way to define them in T-SQL.
2. Use a loop to iterate over all values. This is less general solution but quicker to get started with. Performance is worse although it might not matter.